# How to wait for Grid execution spinner with Java Explicit WebDriver Wait

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait, explicit

I have a grid in my page that been refreshed with variety of actions (reloading, sorting, filtering, etc). Every time one of the actions been applied spinner appears in front of grid until data in grid been reloaded. It may take from 300 to 3000 ms for spinner to appear and spinner may stay there for a few seconds. In same cases grid been reloaded without spinner but it's no way to predict it appearance. Is there any way to take care of waiting for that spinner with Explicit WebDriver Wait without getting an NoSuchElementException?

Comment: The whole idea behind WebDriverWait is to wait for an element to appear on the screen before timing out. If your spinner is unpredictable and doesn't always appear you could try to account for it and handle it as an error condition but I would try to find a different element that is more consistent, is there another element you can use?

Answer (score 0):

Using Firebug, check the attributes of the spinner. Most of the times they have width/height attribute. You can get the attribute value when spinner is displayed and not displayed. You can then write logic to wait till the attribute has the non-displayed value.

Comment: The problem is it has non-displayed value before it would kick off. So there is no way to know if value is "before" or "after" appearance

Answer (score 0):

First you wait for the spinner to appear, then you wait for it to disappear.

In the first wait, you give it a short timeout (maybe 2 seconds, maybe 10), but don't throw any exception if it times out. Just move on (since it probably means the spinner appeared and disappeared faster than selenium could detect it).

Then in the second wait, give it a longer timeout and throw an exception if the spinner is still present at the end.